# Values inserted into combobox are undefined

Tags: javascript, combobox, dhtmlx

So I've created a combobox as such and when I attempt to insert using the `addOption` function it appears to work on some level.  It shows a place in the combobox where it should be but it's a blank space.  When I click on it, it shows undefined.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var infoCellList = [
    {type: "settings", position: "label-left", labelWidth: 90, inputWidth: 130},
    {type: "combo", name: "truckSelect", label: "Truck", value: ""}
    ];

var myFormInformation = vehicles_layout.cells('a').attachForm(infoCellList);
var truckSelectCombo = myFormInformation.getCombo("truckSelect");
truckSelectCombo.addOption("This is a test");
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your current code and post the link.

Comment: You are only defining value and not label; pass in second argument and it should work: `truckSelectCombo.addOption("myval","This is a test");`